# How to simulate ToString method by expression?#

Tags: c#, expression

all
How can I simulate `ToString()` method by expression?
For example:

```
public class test
{
    public string id{get;set;}
}


ParameterExpression parameter1 = Expression.Parameter(typeof(class), "a");
MemberExpression member1 = Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter1, "id");
MethodCallExpression call1 = Expression.Call(typeof(int).GetMethod("ToString"), member1);
Console.WriteLine(call1);
```

But system report AmbiguousMatchException at

> MethodCallExpression call1 =
>   Expression.Call(typeof(int).GetMethod("ToString"), member1);

Answer (score 3):

There are 4 variants of Int32.ToString() method (without parameter, with IFormatProvider parameter, with string format parameter etc). 
You need to explicitly specify which one you need by providing Type[] of input arguments (I assume you need the one without parameters):

```
MethodCallExpression call1 = Expression.Call(typeof(int).GetMethod("ToString", Type.EmptyTypes), member1);
```